# Regroup columns in a df hierarchically?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a set of data with multiple experiences. Two for `egg`, two for `spam` :

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
name,egg1,egg2,spam1,spam2
foo,4,8,15,16
bar,23,42,66,83
"""))

>>> df.set_index('name')

      egg1  egg2  spam1  spam2
name
foo      4     8     15     16
bar     23    42     66     83
```

What I would like to get is something like this :

```
           egg          spam
         1     2      1      2
name
foo      4     8     15     16
bar     23    42     66     83
```

I read about Multiindex and indexslice, but I haven't found how to use them properly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the columns, which convert to a MultiIndex, and drop the empty level:

```
(df.set_index('name')
   .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(df.columns
                                 .str
                                 .split(r"(\d)", expand = True)
                                 .droplevel(-1), 
                               axis = 1, 
                               )
        )
  )

     egg     spam    
       1   2    1   2
name                 
foo    4   8   15  16
bar   23  42   66  83
```

Of course, a cleaner way would be to do it in steps:

Set `name` as index:

```
df = df.set_index('name')
```

Create MultiIndex via `str.split`, setting `expand = True`:

```
 df.columns = df.columns.str.split(r"(\d)", expand = True).droplevel(-1)

 df

     egg     spam    
       1   2    1   2
name                 
foo    4   8   15  16
bar   23  42   66  83
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) method:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['egg','egg','spam','spam'],[1,2,1,2]])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
        egg     spam
        1   2   1   2
name                
foo     4   8   15  16
bar     23  42  66  83
```